# Find $\min x^TAy+b^Tx+c^Ty$ subject to $1^Tx=1^Ty=1,x\ge 0,y\ge 0$

Tags: inequality, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The problem seems to be easy but I can't find a solution :(

**Problem:** Given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, A\ge 0, b\in\mathbb{R}^{m}, c\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Minimize $f(x,y) = x^TAy+b^Tx+c^Ty$ subject to $1^Tx=1^Ty=1,x\ge 0,y\ge 0$.

Thank you in advance for any help.

**Update:**

Since $1^Tx=1^Ty=1$ we have $$x^TAy+b^Tx+c^Ty = x^TAy+(x^Tb)(1^Ty)+(x^T1)(c^Ty) = x^T(A+b1^T+1c^T)y.$$ Thus if we denote $D=A+b1^T+1c^T$ then the problem is reduced to:
\begin{align}
\mbox{minimize}\quad & x^TDy \\
\mbox{subject to}\quad & 1^Tx=1^Ty=1, \\
& x\ge 0,y\ge 0.
\end{align}

Comment: You can use lagrange multipliers to transform this into a linear problem.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers will certainly not linearize the objective. Though it is worth a try, certainly! This is not a convex problem, however, so I've removed that tag.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Thanks. Problem solved :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum value is the smallest component $d_{ij}$ of $D$, attained when $x_i=y_j=1$. I posted the solution [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/18775/find-min-xtay-subject-to-1tx-1ty-1-x-ge-0-y-ge-0).